# SQL How to select one of two nearly identical rows

Tags: sql, select

To help clarify further, as it isn't really occurring to me how to generalize this easily... lets say I have the following rows in a table of the packaged products at a grocery store:

```
PRODUCT ---------- TYPE ---------- PRICE ---------- ITM KEY
APPLE             device            $5               1117
APPLE X10 RED     device            $5               1117
ORANGE X20        device            $6               1189
BANANA            device            $4               1175
BANANA X5         device            $4               1175
KIWI X5           device            $7               1201
```

This represents a table that has updated their database to include the extra info about how many come in the package at the end of the name of the product. Unfortunately, the person that went in forgot to delete the previous data, so any selects will include the duplicate, old data as well as the new row. Since there is no indicator of date to determine when the product was updated and the info after the product name can vary, how would I select JUST the newer row?

Thanks guys.

Comment: Hmm, is `PRODUCT` a string? If so, why is it a string? And why does that string contain another information?

Comment: Did my answer work for you?  If so, please accept it.  If not, please respond and let me know what did not work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If all of the newer rows have the quantity in them, and the older rows don't, you can try something like this:

```
Select * from MyTable
where [Product] like '%X[0-9]%'
```

Alternatively, if all the newer rows have something additional added to the name, try this:

```
Select * from (
  Select *
  , ROW_NUMBER() over (partition by ItmKey order by len(product) desc) RN
  from MyTable
  ) a
where a.RN = 1
```

The first option selects every row where the name of the product includes 'X' followed by a number.  The second will return, for each `item ID`, the row with the longest product name.

Comment: @JohnsonGale - if these do not work for you, please let me know why and I will suggest alternatives.

Comment: You mean, the second query will return the row with the shortest product name for each item key.

Comment: @VladimirBaranov I don't think so...shouldn't the `desc` order it longest first?  Did I miss something?

Comment: I'm sorry, I misread the question and was confused. Your query does what is needed and your description of the query is correct.